# Regex pattern for any string in between

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace strings like

```
Dependencies\myfolder\1\2\abc.dll
Dependencies\myfolder\abc.dll
Dependencies\myfolder\1\abc.dll
```

with

```
packages\abc.dll.
```

What is the suitable regex pattern to do this. I was expecting the pattern to be -

```
Dependencies*abc.dll
```

So my code is -

```
 var newEntry = packages\abc.dll;
 var pattern = Dependencies*abc.dll;
 var allText = ""; //this contains the text read from a file
 Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
 rgx.Replace(allText, newEntry);
```

But this seems to be a wrong regex pattern.

Comment: I think you could use a mere [`var s = newEntry.Substring(newEntry.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1); Console.WriteLine("packages\\" + s);`](http://ideone.com/SqLasE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there you need the `.*` like:

```
Dependencies(.*)abc.dll
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rN6zQ0/1)

**[.NET Online Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrn31M)**